# In Altium, top overlay looks like bottom overlay

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I pressed something by mistake and now my top overlay looks like bottom overlay. Bottom overlay looks like top overlay. It can be seen from the picture.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I think Ctrl+F to flip the board?

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Comment: You are very welcome! Please accept @JYeltons answer so that the bots won't revive this questions unnecessarily in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the board from the front or back. In the **View Configuration** panel, select the checkbox for "View From Bottom Side" or press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> hot key.

This is useful when you want to inspect bottom-layer silkscreen without having it mirrored. When doing so, the top-layer silkscreen will mirror, of course.

[image: Altium Designer view configuration panel]